# Get the List of Songs based Song Albums

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-sqlite

How can I get the list of songs using the Album Name? I've tried most of the codes but the issue is that the whole songs ArrayList gets added up with all the songs again and again.

Means the each album as key will have an arraylist and each arraylist is having all the songs in it.

---

Here's the code:

```
public void getHashMap()   {
        Map<String,String> albumTitle = new TreeMap<>(list.getSortedAlbumTitleTreeMap(getContext()));
        Map<String,String> titleAlbum = new TreeMap<>(list.getSortedTitleAlbumTreeMap(getContext()));

        ArrayList<String> albumList = new ArrayList<>(titleAlbum.keySet());

        ArrayList<String> newAlbum = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> newSongs = new ArrayList<>(list.getSongs(getContext()));
        HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> finalAlbum = new HashMap<>();

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "albumList size: " + albumList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        for (int i = 0;i<albumList.size();i++)  {
            String albumName = albumList.get(i);
            for (int j = 0;j<titleAlbum.size();j++)   {
                String key = titleAlbum.keySet().toArray()[j].toString();
                String value = titleAlbum.get(key);
                /*Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Entering IF....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                if (albumName.equals(value))  {
                    /*Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Entered IF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                    newAlbum.add(key);
                }
            }
            finalAlbum.put(albumName,newAlbum);
        }
    }
```

---

> Also what is the Difference and use of AlbumID and Album Name?
>
> Is it possible to get Songs using Album ID? How?

Comment: Why cant you use some model with album id,album name and list of songs . Instead of using so many arraylist and hashmaps

Comment: Will that be helpful? Also please help me regarding Album Id and it's relation with Album Name